# Error getting php variable in other jquery file embedded in it

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a from page for displaying question which is fetching data from mysql

```
<?php
include('lib/db.php');
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$cid=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
//echo $sub;
$rs=mysql_query("select * from category where id='$cid'");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$q=rand(1,2);
$rs1=mysql_query("select * from questions where qid='$q'");

$r1=mysql_fetch_array($rs1);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tsubmit.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<header>
<?php echo $r['cat_name'];?> Test
</header>
<form method="post" id="test" role="form">
<label for="question">Question:</label>
<?php echo $r1['question']; ?><br/>
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $r1['ans1']; ?>" name="ans1" /><?php echo $r1['ans1']; ?>
<br/><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $r1['ans2']; ?>" name="ans1" /><?php echo $r1['ans2']; ?>
<br/><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $r1['ans3']; ?>" name="ans1" /><?php echo $r1['ans3']; ?>
<br/><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $r1['ans4']; ?>" name="ans1" /><?php echo $r1['ans4']; ?>
<br/><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>


</body> 
</html>
```

and the embedded tsubmit.js is

```
$(document).ready(function()
                           {
var start;
start= new Date()/1000;
function submit(x){
       var end=new Date()/1000;
           var timespent=end-x;
           alert(timespent);
           var ans=$('input[name=ans1]:checked').val();
           alert(ans);
           var cans="<?php echo $r['ans']; ?>";
           //alert('<?php echo $r["ans"]; ?>');
           alert(cans);
          // var qid="<?php echo $q; ?>";
           alert(qid);
           //var datastring='ans='+ans+'&timespent='+timespent+'cans='+cans+'qid='+qid;
           $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url:"result.php",
                  data:'ans='+ans+'&timespent='+timespent+'&cans='+cans+'&qid='+qid                                           //success:success()
                  });

       }


        $("#test").submit(function(event){
        alert('user clicked submit');                  
           submit(start);
           //event.preventDefault();
       });
   });
```

but i'm not value of cans and also result.php isn't getting anything

```
<?php
  include('lib/db.php');
  echo $_POST['ans'];
  echo "<script> alert('ans')</script>";
  ?>
```

`echo $_post['ans']` isn't getting anything

Comment: don't echo tech from php directly into a js context. you risk killing the script with syntax errors. ALWAYS use `json_encode()`.

Comment: and you're loading your tsubmit page via `<script>` tag. that means theclient browser will request that via a completely SEPARATE http request, and any variables you were doing in your php script that output the main html will **NOT** be present.

Comment: and of course, any php code in the .js file will NOT be executed, as webserver generally aren't told to treat .js files as php scripts.

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery? you can get the values of input with the id

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcB wrote, the JavaScript files with PHP will not execute. There are ways to do it, yet as was already mentioned, it is not advised.

In your HTML `head` tag, you cna define a script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tsubmit.php"></script>
```

This will call the file via PHP and result in JS. Still wont get the PHP you're expecting.